# What is going to happen if I activate oem windows on two computers?

Tags: windows, windows-activation, oem

What if I activate oem os with a key on a computer and after do the same on another? What will be displayed on the firts computer, which one will be blocked?

Comment: **Only one will actually activate.**

Answer (score -1):

This is closely related and applies to XP. If you take an image file from one PC and load it onto another PC (and they could be completely different computers and you used something like Macrium Redeploy, or both could be exactly the same model, and the same outcome still applies) the computer will say the hardware has changed and you need to activate Windows. You say okay and it goes ahead. You can repeat this process several times and then after x times (less than 10 I think) it says the activation key has been used too many times and it will not activate unless you ring up.
At this point you can use another activation key. Change the key using Joshua key reader. But it must be the right type. I think in some way it matches the PID. If you got hold of another PC like the original, then you can use that key, which will match. It will work, but it is against Microsoft's policy for it to be used on two at once. That is why they will only activate it a few times with each compatible key.  Unfortunately, this means if you really genuinely keep transferring your XP from one machine to another, for example to upgrade from one  make to another, or to reload on a new one exactly the same as a broken old one, unfortunately if you are genuine and always just have one copy of XP and keep moving it, it will not activate after X number of moves. But you can still ring up and explain and they might allow it.
But to answer your question, no blocking of earlier installs on other machines takes place, just the latest one will not activate.